# Sony Vaio SVP132A1CM stuck on boot

Tags: boot, 13.10, vaio

I Have Sony Vaio Ultrabook model SVP132A1CM and it freezes when I try to boot from USB:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How did you create the USB?  Also do an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the downloaded ISO file.

Comment: Yes I did, and I created the bootable USB using Rufus application

Comment: Try creating using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: It works when I used Unebootin, do you have any Idea why? what is the diif between unebootin and rufus?

Comment: I don't use rufus, I never have heard of rufus, somehow I know why now ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNetBootin application instead of Rufus, and it works.